# Differences between ModalDrawer and drawerContent from Scaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Technically it's the same component but I really don't know if it's a correct practice add a `ModalDrawer` into `drawerContent`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModalDrawer` is [used](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/c6f24564d51bff3c42a7efc9ccb7ec734301836b/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Scaffold.kt#L196) by `Scaffold` under the hood, so you definitely shouldn't add it into `drawerContent`.

You can use it as independent element, if you don't need other `Scaffold` features, or as part of `Scaffold`, your `drawerContent` should look the same in both cases.